# Implement a new custom sensor in gazebo ignition

Tags: gazebo, sensors, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress, gazebo-sensor

I'm trying to implement a new custom sensor in gazebo ignition, more specifically I want to implement a light sensor that will simply output a light value based on the distance between the sensor and a light source. I followed this tutorial on [how to create a custom sensor](https://gazebosim.org/api/sensors/6.1/custom_sensors.html) but I don't know how to proceed and how to adapt the code for my interest. I understood that I should modify the `Load` function but where can I find information for example on how to get the position of the light from the sdf file.

Any help will be appreciated.